# Optimisation code jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to display a button according to the value of a string !!

I have two type of button:

button value = "Add"
button value = "Update"

```
<p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
                    Result 
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{LigneXL.resultat}" />
            <p:commandButton value="ADD NEW"  rendered="#{LigneXL.resultat eq 'Not exist'}"></p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton value="MAJ"      rendered="#{LigneXL.resultat eq 'Is FMD'}"></p:commandButton>  
        </p:column>  
        <p:column>
```

is there another way to make it works !!I think my methode is wrong because every time there is a button created !!
thank you in advance

Comment: When rendered="false" the component is not executed... I don't think that could be more optimized!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the code that I'm tried to optimize,

```
       <p:column  headerText="Result">  
            <h:outputText value="#{LigneXL.resultat}" />
            <p:commandButton value="#{LigneXL.resultat eq 'Not exist'?'ADD NEW':'MAJ'}"  rendered="#{(LigneXL.resultat eq 'Not exist') or LigneXL.resultat eq 'Is FMD'}">  
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{LigneXL.resultat}" target="#{yourBean.targetString}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
```

Make a String object in yourBean and according to targetString value do your business logic